# Why should we make unit testing file separate with source file?

Tags: c, unit-testing

We have a requirement that *the unit testing file need to be separate with the source file in project building*.

It means we must not do this for testing the source file.

***unit_testing_file.c***

```
#include <source_file.c>

//testcases for testing source_file.c
...
```

Two problems I can see here are just:

- About linking (the test file and source file become 1 object file after compiling instead of 2)
- The scope of variables in two file now become same.

That leads to including source file in test file could be a bad practise. But it's not really convince me enough.

Is there any big another reason behind the scene that with it we must not include the source file in test file ?

Comment: shouldn't you include a header that have forward declaration of tested function, instead of directly including the C file ?

Comment: @dvhh That depends entirely on the nature of the tests. If you are testing internals of the translation unit, you can't do that. But if you are doing "black box" testing, then including the header file would be correct.

Comment: @dvhh I did do it and I'm finding the reason that I should do it. I've edit the question for more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty common when testing C. The reason it's done this way is that it allows you to "punch through" some of C's (rather weak) abstraction and data hiding.

For instance, consider a unit that has a `static` variable whose value you need to check in the tests. You can't access that from a different translation unit (i.e. C file) since it's `static`, and if the unit (module) doesn't have a getter for the variable, your test can't inspect it.

By `#include`ing the C file under test into the test code, they compile as the same translation unit and you can access even `static` variables.

Comment: I do understand about this, like I said *the scope of variables in two file now become same*, I'm trying to find other reasons.

Comment: I've update my question for more clearly. Could you check it again ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the requirement could be as simple as "because the boss said so" - you'll have to ask the one who gave you the requirement.

AFAIK, there is no *technical* reason not to do the `#include <source.c>` thing. Rather, that's the least-ugly way in C to have access to things that normally would be off-limits, like static functions and variables; as you said, with the `#include` you're in the same scope as in the source.c file.

As for your mention of the object files becoming one, I don't see how that could matter. And anyway one could argue that that's pretty much the definition of linking.

If what you really want is to get an excuse to fight that requirement (that's what I would do!), I would just try to make an unit test for a static function in a source.c file, and show it as an example how much uglier things get without using the `#include`.

And why would I fight the requirement, or at least question it? Because as said, the alternatives are even uglier:

- helper functions to give external access to static functions and variables = extra boilerplate, might get tricky if there is a lot of interactions among statics. Might go against some coding guidelines, which explicitly forbid using different code for testing and for production.
- `#ifdefs` to remove the helper code = complicates the production source, goes against some coding guidelines
- `#define static` = yep, that's right, I've seen unit test frameworks do that to simply obliterate the `static`. Horrible, messes up scope, changes behavior of static vars!
- separate branches, one with only production code and another with production+test/helper code = crazy duplication, copypaste hell, maintenance nightmare. No sane "guideline" would corner you into this case.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this are overall design decisions.

Obviously, it has merits to keep the test independent from the actual code. That lack of tight coupling between the actual code and the test would be the main argument why; changes in the test should never be allowed to affect the actual code. Any mission-critical program would have requirements to keep the test separate for this purpose.

Another philosophy is to always develop the test at the same time as you develop the code (buzzword: "TDD"), because all code needs to be tested and you are most able to write relevant tests when you have all the detailed functionality of the code still in your head, i.e. during development. Some designs include the test as part of the code module being developed. The strongest argument for this philosophy is that the quality of the tests themselves usually becomes better, and that you implicitly guarantee that the code is always tested.

But while there is merit in having the person developing the code writing the tests - to make them the most relevant, there is also a disadvantage: as a programmer you tend to be blind against obvious mistakes made in your own code. To have another person with different views look at the code is therefore always a very good idea. Similarly, it might be wise to have another person write the tests, to verify that the program follows the specification.

---

As for your specific case, there is a beginner-level program design rule that goes like: if you ever find yourself `#include`:ing a C file anywhere in your program, your program design is fundamentally flawed. When the need to do this pops up, it almost always means that your whole program is in very bad shape and needs to be rewritten from scratch.

Now, testing is a different matter. What would be regarded as 100% bad practice in production code might be ok during tests. For the sake of testing, you should keep tests of the translation unit internals internal. These test could/should later be removed upon production release. Depending of what your coding standard says, a compiler switch might be sufficient. If the production code is not allowed to contain any tests, then simply remove that code. (You can keep 2 versions of the file in your version control system. Put the test version in a "branch" of its own).

If the tests are "black box" testing, as in you are only testing the translation unit's interface, then there is no need to access the internals at all.

Comment: so basically, you mean `#include`ing a C file in test file are ok.

Comment: @Codino It depends on what you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for not including your .c source into your test source is that you don't do that in your production code - you compile it into its own compilation unit and link it in order to use it. Your test should act just as any other "customer" and link in the compilation unit to be tested.

By acting as just another customer, the test can expose problems that the production code can also encounter using the same compilation unit.

Doing it the other way, including in source code, "contaminates" your code with your test code - mixed into the same compilation unit - and it can actually mask problems.